# How to add styles to rows in display:table

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

The following is my code.... It is running perfectly in every browser except Firefox... In Firefox, the bottom border of the row is not visible... How can I fix it?

```
  <display:table class="displayTableBorder" export="false" style="width:95%;" rules="rows" summary="Plan actions and notes" name="planSummaryDTO.listPlanNoteDto" uid="planNote" rules="rows" requestURI="" pagesize="2">

 <display:column class="table-row" style="border:1px solid black;" title="Action" headerClass="hixTableHeader header" class="displayTagtd" style="width: 10%;text-align: center;">

   <a href="javascript:showUpdateWindow('UPDATE','${planNote.noteId}');" style="FONT-SIZE: 14px;font-family: Vegur;color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration:underline;font-weight:normal">${planNote.action}</a>
</display:column>

<display:column style="border:1px solid black;" property="createdDate" style="width: 20%;text-align: center;"  title="Date" headerClass="hixTableHeader header" class="displayTagtd" />
            </display:table>
```

Comment: Try using : `-moz-border-bottom:1px solid black;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are code generates table then remove inline styles and use the following CSS

```
 <style>
 table, table tr, table tr td
 {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    -moz-border: 1px solid gray;
    -webkit-border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 </style>
```

If above code not works for your then send me your generated code here. I will solve your problem.

Comment: <table id="planNote" class="displayTableBorder" rules="rows" style="width:95%;" summary="Plan actions and notes">
<caption>Plan actions and notes table</caption>
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="empty">
<td colspan="2">Nothing found to display.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: you are missing </thead> in your code. and it is working in all browser. Don't forget to mark as answer.